# How can i show my html page in windows phone web brower?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

i hav a local html page. i want to show that image in windows phone's web browser. How it will be possible. M using this code and its not working. Kindly suggest me. Currently i am using this code.

```
Uri imgUri = new Uri("camera.html", UriKind.Relative);
        webBrowser1.Navigate(imgUri);
```

Kindly suggest me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check...

- When you specify the file contents in the solution, is the build action set to "Content"?
- Is the file you want to display saved in isolated storage?  If not, you will need to put it there.

*For help on the actual steps you need to take to move a content file into a file in isolated storage (and then display its contents in the WebBrowser control), follow [this guide on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431811%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)*